# Resetting numbers back to 0 on new month

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a window with controls that insert data in ms.access table.
My table is like this:

```
ID | Number | Name
1  | 1      | Ace
2  | 2      | Paul
```

First I pull the last 'Number' from the table, and add it +1 so the next entry in the table will be 'Number + 1', or:

```
ID | Number | Name
3  | 3      | Kiwi

int Numb1 = XNumber + 1; // XNumber is the last 'Number' in table.
textbox1.Text = Numb1 + "/" + DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
```

The textbox1 displays the following:

```
'3/10'
```

Every time I add a new record, that records 'Number' is increased by 1. What I'm trying to acomplish is have the numbers reset back to 0 when we enter in a new month. 
So if the textbox displays '3/10' and I keep inserting data until the end of the month, when I insert data in the new month I want the textbox to display '1/11'.

In the table that should look something like this:

```
ID | Number | Name
4  | 1      | Stellar
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, much appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
ID | Number | Name | DateofEntry
1  | 1      | Ace  | 10/22/2018
2  | 2      | Paul | 10/23/2018
3  | 3      | Kiwi | 10/25/2018
```

Comment: If you don't store the month and year in your table, you won't be able to differentiate the data you enter in this month or other month or same month but different year.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do store the date in the table, I oversimplified my question to be understandable. I don't know how to proceed, if you could point me where to read up on how to do that please

Comment: Post your table with the date.

Comment: You should probably include the relevant data, which would include storing the month. In that case, when you grab the last `Number` value, also grab the last `Month` value, so that you can determine if this entry is a different month than the last entry. You should also store `private int LastMonth;` at the class level, in case the month changes while they're still entering data locally.

Comment: @RufusL Don't forget the year too.

Comment: All right, OP didn't say anything about year. It's just my preference to reset the number every time the month changes, including year.

Comment: That's how the table looks, I store month/day/year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you grab the last record to get the last `Number` value store that number, along with the last `Month` value, in private class-level variables. This way you can determine if the current entry is a different month than the previous entry, and can update both the `LastEntryNumber` and `LastEntryMonth` values.

For example:

```
// These are initially populated from the last row of the table when the program loads
private int LastEntryNumber;
private int LastEntryMonth;

// Sample code enclosed in a method body
private void AddEntry()
{
    // Update the last month if needed (as well as the last entry number)
    if (DateTime.Today.Month != LastEntryMonth)
    {
        LastEntryMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;
        LastEntryNumber = 0;
    }

    // Increment our number
    LastEntryNumber = LastEntryNumber + 1;
    textbox1.Text = LastEntryNumber + "/" + LastEntryMonth;
}
```

Note that the last two lines, which increment the `LastEntryNumber` and display the value, can be combined and simplified to one line:

```
// Increment our number and display the new value
textbox1.Text = ++LastEntryNumber + "/" + LastEntryMonth;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.